# How a non-generic class can result in a runtime error

Tags: java, generics

I've been learning about generics and looked through some examples from docs.oracle.com

On oracle's tutorial it says: "One part of the code may place an Integer in the box and expect to get Integers out of it, while another part of the code may mistakenly pass in a String, resulting in a runtime error."

I recreated the following box class they use as an example of a non-generic class to try to create a runtime error to better understand generics, however I have not been able to succeed.

How could the box class result in a runtime error due to not being a generic class? I would love to see an example as I was not able to create one myself.

```
public class box {

    private Object object;

    public void set (Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
    public Object get() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Class names should use CamelCase, so your class should really be called `Box`.

Answer (score 2):

You can reproduce the issue by constructing a `Box` object holding a `String` and expecting to get an `Integer` out. For this to be accepted by the compiler you need to use an explicit cast:

```
Box b = new Box();
b.set("a string");
Integer i = (Integer) b.get();
```

The last line will fail with a `ClassCastException`.